# jQuery lazy-loading image and video not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, lazy-loading

I'm trying to lazy-load an image & video file with jQuery, following the example from the URL below:

https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-videos.html

https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-images.html

The problem is that my paginated data loaded `onScroll` by jQuery, but all of my image and video wasn't loaded. How can I solve this?

**[ Pagination ]**

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    page += 1;
    if (page <= maxPages) {
      $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function () {
          $('.loader').html('Loading....');
        },
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'blog/postloader?page=' + page,
        data: { 'page': page },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
          $('.loader').html('Load More...');
          $('.blogItems').append(data);
        }
      });
    }
    else { $('.loader').html('No More Post Available'); }
  }
```

**[ Lazy Loader function ]**

```
function delayImg() {
  var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (var i = 0; i < imgDefer.length; i++) {
    if (imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
      imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src', imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
    }
  }
}
//window.onload = delayImg;

// Lazy Load Video
function delayVid() {
  var vidDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
  for (var i = 0; i < vidDefer.length; i++) {
    if (vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
      vidDefer[i].setAttribute('src', vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
    }
  }
}
//window.onload = delayVid;

function start() {
  delayImg();
  delayVid();
}
window.onload = start;
```

Comment: add this to your success handler: `$('img[data-src], iframe[data-src]').each(function(){
  if(!this.src) this.src = $(this).data("src");
  $(this).removeData("src");
});`

Comment: Are all your images able to load, if not the videos?

Comment: Without lazy loader function both img & videos are loaded perfectly

Comment: @Thomas I just copy & paste ur code in to my success handler before append data but nothing improves

Comment: you have to do this **after** you `.append(data)`

Comment: @Thomas Still nothing changed! I added ur code after append(data), I think because all data is rendering on fly by jquery it's not making any html code in source

Answer (score 2):

you can combine the function with jQuery

```
function delayMedia() {
  $('img, iframe').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).attr('src')) { // set only if src is empty
      var dataSrc = $(this).data('src');
      if (dataSrc)
        this.src = dataSrc;
    }
  });
}
```

call it on page load and after Ajax

```
$('.blogItems').append(data);
delayMedia();
```

And your function are not "really" lazy load, usually it appear after element position reached not on page load

```js
function isVisible(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
    elemTop = rect.top,
    elemBottom = rect.bottom;
  return (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
}

function delayMedia() {
  $('img, iframe').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).attr('src')) { // set only if src is empty
      var dataSrc = $(this).data('src');
      if (dataSrc && isVisible(this)){
        console.log(dataSrc)
        this.src = dataSrc;
      }
    }
  });
}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  delayMedia();
});
```

```css
.dh {
  height: 300px;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="dh">scroll</p>
<img src="" data-src="https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/1712173free-wallpaper.jpg" />
<p class="dh">scroll</p>
<img src="" data-src="https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/3d_falling_leaves.jpg" />
<p class="dh">scroll</p>
<img src="" data-src="https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/free-wallpapers-640x400.jpg" />
```